# Do non-smartphones exist that are able to sync with any OS after Mountain Lion?

Tags: data-synchronization, macos, contacts, calendar

Currently I have a Nokia 6300 and a Mac with Mountain Lion installed. Calendar and Contacts sync through iSync via Bluetooth without a problem.

I'm thinking of upgrading to Mavericks or Yosemite, but as these newer OS'es miss the syncing services necessary for iSync to work I wouldn't be able to connect my Nokia anymore.

I don't want to buy a smartphone just so it will sync with my Mac, so therefore I'm looking for a "dumbphone" that can sync with my Mac on Mavericks or Yosemite.

So my question is:

Does a dumbphone exist that will be able to sync contacts and calendars with a Mac on Mavericks or Yosemite? It's fine if a third-party application is needed.

Comment: Get something in-between maybe. I suppose most phones with WiFi should support syncing calDAV accounts, so you could use a syncing service like google, iCloud, etc. - I'm not really up-to-date on which dumbphones/featurephones are still sold internationally so I can't recommend a specific model.

Comment: I thought that the term "dumbphone" implied it didn't have WiFi. Maybe bluetooth. 'Cause with WiFi it's indeed quite easy to set-up syncing.

Comment: Well yes that's true. But afaik any device that has an OS advanced enough to support something like syncing (such as symbian) would be a feature phone (such as your 6300 is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Mate 4 was best to support Nokia S40 sync over Bluetooth.

Yet it is not working under 10.9 or 10.10. And their new version 5 dropped support for S40 altogether.

So going further probably the only way is to setup Virtual Machine with older OS of your choosing and run it from time to time just to sync.